# \pagestyle{plain} for the abstract and \fancypagestyle for the the chapter pages

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, pagestyle

I want to use \pagestyle{plain} for the abstract and \pagestyle{fancy} for the chapter pages. But it's not working. It would be a great pleasure if anyone could help me with this. Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage{mathptmx}%times Roman
\usepackage{caption}

%maths
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}%mathematical facilities for latex
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm} %curl F and similar
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{romannum}
\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}


%tikzpicture
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

%pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

%colours
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
%To add a navigation window
\usepackage[pdftex]{pict2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,allcolors=purple}
\usepackage{hypcap}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{array,boldline, makecell, booktabs}%for creating a table
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{verbatim} %for multiline comments
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{} % delete current header and footer
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}% space for the rule
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{} % get rid of headers on plain pages
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % and the line
}

\begin{document}
\input{title}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\input{title2}
\input{title3}

\frontmatter
\pagestyle{plain}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Declaration}
\include{authorship}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\include{abstract}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
\include{ack} 

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\pagestyle{fancy}
\mainmatter


%%%%%%%%%%% MAIN CONTENT %%%%%%%%%%%%
\include{Chapters/Chapter1}  
\include{Chapters/Chapter2}  
\include{Chapters/Chapter3}
\include{Chapters/Chapter4}
\include{Chapters/Chapter5}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to add `\pagestyle{fancy}` somewhere after `\pagestyle{plain}`. The command is a switch; it sets the document style, here `plain`, from that line onward. I can't see `\pagestyle{fancy}` in the document body, so I assume the page style will be `plain`, apart from first titles. I can only assume that because your code doesn't compile due to missing `\documentclass{}` and other files.

Comment: My bad. I used \pagestyle{fancy} in my document body but forgot to add it here. But still, it's not working. Thanks very much. @Celdor

Comment: It should work. Perhaps if you try to explicitly define `fancy` as you do with `plain`.Also, remember any page with a chapter title gets the `plain` pagestyle as default. This can be changed with `\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{<another style>}}{}{}` and requires to load `etoolbox`.

Comment: @NasrinAkterTanya What do you mean by "it's not working"? That sentence has very little information. Please tell what you expect, and what you get instead. Or if you get error messages. One thing to note: often you should give a `\newpage` or `\clearpage` before changing the pagestyle.